# Mac shut down on a Kernel Panic - 2019 Intel Core i9

Tags: kernel-panic

My 2019 16-inch MacBook Pro has concurrent kernel panics. Any help on this would be very appreciated, I don't really know what's happening.

[image: mac software version]

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80039aac4f): Spinlock[0xffffff801bd5ba80] timeout after 1152007950 ticks ;lock owner thread=0x200000000000, current_thread: 0xffffffa52910cb30, lock owner active on CPU -1, start time: 4597826228808, now: 4598978236758, timeout: 1152000000 @locks_i386.c:487
Panicked task 0xffffffa06056f8b8: 140 threads: pid 733: Dropbox
Backtrace (CPU 2), panicked thread: 0xffffffa52910cb30, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffd0a67ef510 : 0xffffff80038705fd mach_kernel : _handle_debugger_trap + 0x4ad
0xffffffd0a67ef560 : 0xffffff80039c4b84 mach_kernel : _kdp_i386_trap + 0x114
0xffffffd0a67ef5a0 : 0xffffff80039b4619 mach_kernel : _kernel_trap + 0x3c9
0xffffffd0a67ef600 : 0xffffff8003810951 mach_kernel : _return_from_trap + 0xc1
0xffffffd0a67ef620 : 0xffffff80038708dd mach_kernel : _DebuggerTrapWithState + 0x5d
0xffffffd0a67ef710 : 0xffffff800386ff87 mach_kernel : _panic_trap_to_debugger + 0x1a7
0xffffffd0a67ef770 : 0xffffff8003fdd09b mach_kernel : _panic + 0x84
0xffffffd0a67ef860 : 0xffffff80039aac4f mach_kernel : _lck_spin_lock_grp + 0xbf
0xffffffd0a67ef8c0 : 0xffffff8003887c04 mach_kernel : _lck_spinlock_timeout_set_orig_ctid + 0x204
0xffffffd0a67ef940 : 0xffffff8003954a02 mach_kernel : _vm_page_insert_internal + 0xe2
0xffffffd0a67ef9b0 : 0xffffff800393c716 mach_kernel : _vm_page_sleep + 0x13f6
0xffffffd0a67efab0 : 0xffffff800393dbcd mach_kernel : _vm_object_lock_try + 0x33d
0xffffffd0a67efb10 : 0xffffff800392ce98 mach_kernel : _vm_map_copyin_internal + 0x738
0xffffffd0a67efc10 : 0xffffff800392e979 mach_kernel : _vm_map_fork + 0x609
0xffffffd0a67efcb0 : 0xffffff80038b03e7 mach_kernel : _task_create_internal + 0xd7
0xffffffd0a67efdd0 : 0xffffff8003d2e206 mach_kernel : _fork_create_child + 0x76
0xffffffd0a67efe50 : 0xffffff8003d2d1b7 mach_kernel : _lf_abort_advlocks + 0x367
0xffffffd0a67efe90 : 0xffffff8003d2cfcb mach_kernel : _lf_abort_advlocks + 0x17b
0xffffffd0a67efef0 : 0xffffff8003d2e7a6 mach_kernel : _fork + 0x36
0xffffffd0a67eff40 : 0xffffff8003e60020 mach_kernel : _unix_syscall64 + 0x1e0
0xffffffd0a67effa0 : 0xffffff8003810d96 mach_kernel : _hndl_unix_scall64 + 0x16

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffffa52910cb30): Dropbox
Boot args: keepsyms=1

Mac OS version:
22E261

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:17 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: CF2A42DA-3F7C-30C6-9433-6F2076FF1F94
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000003400000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8003600000
Kernel slide:      0x00000000034dc000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff80036dc000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8003500000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1801486238075
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000001a370f28442
  Sleep   : 0x0000019b7f839bae 0x00000004d04390aa 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000019b95eecea2 0x0000041caacb9202 0x0000019b93c4a1c7
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff905c077000 - 0xffffffb05c077000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff905c077000 - 0xffffff9060078000
  . VM    : 0xffffff9060078000 - 0xffffff952c3ab000
  . RO    : 0xffffff952c3ab000 - 0xffffff96c5a11000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff96c5a11000 - 0xffffff9b91d44000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff9b91d44000 - 0xffffffa05e077000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffa05e077000 - 0xffffffa52a3aa000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffa52a3aa000 - 0xffffffa9f66dd000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffa9f66dd000 - 0xffffffb05c077000
  Metadata: 0xffffffd07d22e000 - 0xffffffd09d22e000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffd09d22e000 - 0xffffffd0a322e000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

last started kext at 9914788237: >AGPM  131 (addr 0xffffff7f98636000, size 126976)
loaded kexts:
>AGPM   131
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    6440.7
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.1.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
>!AGFXHDA   240.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    340.1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    20.0.5
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 7.1.18
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   7.1.18
>AGDCBacklightControl   7.1.18
>pmtelemetry    1
@filesystems.nfs    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  198.100.13
>!AMuxControl2  7.1.18
>!ABacklight    180.8
@UVCService 1
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 20.0.5
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   340.1
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   627.100.6
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   2142.101.3
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AUserConsent  1
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    403
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.Compression    1
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>!AHIDKeyboard  231
>!AHS!BDriver   6440.7
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AActuatorDriver   6440.7
>!AMultitouchDriver 6440.7
>!AInputDeviceSupport   6440.8
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
>!UAudio    540.8
>!AAudioClockLibs   240.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.1.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!AHDA!C    440.2
|IOHDA!F    440.2
|IOAudio!F  440.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>IOHIDPowerSource   1
>!ACallbackPowerSource  1
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1140.6
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!ARSMChannel   1
|IORSM!F    1
>!AIPAppender   1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  7.1.18
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  597
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   475.40.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1140.25
@!AGPUWrangler  7.1.18
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    7.1.18
|IOGraphics!F   597
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  336.40.12
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  10.5.10
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IO80211!F  1200.13.0
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
|IOSerial!F 11
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1140.25
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  552
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  235.100.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  482.100.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  482.100.4
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACyrus    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   5.0.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: It appears Dropbox is implicated here.  Uninstall DropBox (or boot in Safe Mode) and see if the problem goes away

Comment: how do I boot in Safe Mode? and how do I diagnose if the problem went away when in Safe Mode?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac